# Create method which takes only values as parameter which implements Comparable<T>

Tags: java, oop

I want to get a repeating code into a method, but I could not find a solution.
The method should take a different kind of Type like `String` and `Long` which implements Comparable, in order to use the `compareTo()` function.

**Original:**

```
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_FIRST =
      (o1, o2) -> o1.getFirst() == null ? o2.getFirst() == null ? 0 : -1 : o2.getFirst() == null ? +1 : o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst());
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_SECOND =
      (o1, o2) -> o1.getSecond() == null ? o2.getSecond() == null ? 0 : -1 : o2.getSecond() == null ? +1 : o1.getSecond().compareTo(o2.getSecond());
```

What i tried: (does not work)

```
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_FIRST =
(o1, o2) -> nullProfCompare(o1.getFirst(), o2.getFirst());
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_SECOND =
(o1, o2) -> nullProfCompare(o1.getSecond(), o2.getSecond());

public static int nullProfCompare(Comparable<T> o1, T o2) {
    return o1 == null ? o2 == null ? 0 : -1 : o2 == null ? +1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

I did already try a lot like using `instanceOf`/`isAssignableFrom` but nothing was valid.
How should the method look like to accept only Variables which implements Comparable?

Comment: If you have as many typos in your code as you have in this question, it's amazing you'd ever get your code to compile. There is no `Comperable` type in Java. It's named [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Please clean up the question text.

Comment: Haha praise the auto complete (dyslexics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 already has a null-capable `Comparator` implementations:

- [`Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-)
- [`Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-)

Looks like your `nullProfCompare` is the same as the `nullsFirst` method.

You can also use the [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method to simplify your code:

```
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_FIRST =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getFirst));
Comparator<Pair<String, Long>> PAIR_COMPARATOR_SECOND =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getSecond));
```

---

The problem with your `nullProfCompare` implementation is that you use `T` without ever defining it, and your two parameters are not the same type, which they should be.

Here is the correct implementation:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int nullProfCompare(T o1, T o2) {
    return o1 == null ? o2 == null ? 0 : -1 : o2 == null ? +1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Comment: thank you great answer
I already tried using <T extends Comparable<T>> but at the parameters of the method. I find it wierd to declare the Paramter type in front of the return type.
Haven't done a lot with generics yet.